# How to style Oracle SQL output tables?

Tags: html, css, sql, oracle, vbscript

basically I have a .asp page that runs a SQL query from Application Express and displays a table (code as follows):

```vb
<%
Set DBConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
DBConn.Open "Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};DBQ=ORCL;UID=ops$USERNAME;PWD=PWD;"
Set QueryResult = DBConn.Execute("SELECT * FROM LOAN")
Response.Write "<table border=1 cellpadding=4>"
Response.Write "<tr>"
For I = 0 to QueryResult.Fields.Count - 1
    Response.Write "<td><b>" & QueryResult(I).Name & "</b></td>"
Next
Response.Write "</tr>"
Do While Not QueryResult.EOF
    Response.Write "<tr>"
    For I = 0 To QueryResult.Fields.Count - 1
        Response.Write "<td>" & QueryResult(I) & "</td>"
    Next
    Response.Write "</tr>"
    QueryResult.MoveNext
Loop
Response.Write "</table>"

QueryResult.Close
DBConn.Close

%>
```

The only issue I am having is how to style the table. I have never done this kind of output before and am not sure where I should put the styling rules. I just need it to be the same sort of styling for the rest of the site: sans-serif etc. Another thing is how to change the titles of the displayed columns?

Thanks for any help, I am quite stuck with this as I have never worked with VBScript/Oracle Application Express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'd use standard CSS to style your output by encapsulating it in standard HTML markups, something like:

```
Response.Write "<html>"
Response.Write "<head>"
Response.Write "<style media="screen" type="text/css">"
.. Add style rules here
Response.Write "</style>"
Response.Write "</head>"
Response.Write "<body>"
... Your table here
Response.Write "</body>"
Response.Write "</html>"
```

Then for your table headers, this is standard HTML again:

Response.Write ""

```
Response.Write "<thead>"
Response.Write "<tr>"
Response.Write "<th>1st column name</th>"
Response.Write "<th>2nd column name</th>"
...
Response.Write "</thead>"
Response.Write "<tbody>"
Response.Write "<tr>"
For I = 0 to QueryResult.Fields.Count - 1
... your code
Loop
Response.Write "</tbody>"
Response.Write "</table>"
```

Be careful to escape the quotes of the HTML attributes (`media="screen"`).